# Custom detail page for Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-object, detail-page, detail

I wonder how I can assign a custom Visualforce page to an object detail page on Salesforce1. 
Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you  need to make this page available for SF1. And replace this page with **View** from Object setting page. Now from this page's action method check currently you are in SF1 or in desktop and if you are in desktop then redirect to standard page with parameter `baseurl/id?nooverride=1`.In this way you can make this page available for SF1.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I'm a new user and I don't understand very well... first steps is:
- go in the custom object page and create a "New action" or "New button or link"?

Comment: if it is custom object then go to create>Object>click on object name >  and in Button,Link Action Section Find view and change this with your page. Others step will remain same. You need to use StandardController then your page available here.

Comment: I fear that I can't do that because doing that I replace desktop page too... I want replace only the sf1 one.

Comment: Please read my answer i already mention that how you can only replace your page in SF1 :)

Comment: Oops, you're right, now I try :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it works! I can't vote your answer because I haven't sufficient reputation :( If someone read vote for Tushar Sharma!